# AttributeError: 'UsingForDirective' object has no attribute 'typeName'

Tags: solidity, brownie

I'm trying to compile code from [OHM BondDepository.sol](https://etherscan.io/address/0x575409F8d77c12B05feD8B455815f0e54797381c#code) contract however every time I do so, I get this error from brownie

```
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.7.5
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
Generating build data...
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 40, in main
    active_project = project.load()
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 751, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 238, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 95, in _compile
    build_json = compiler.compile_and_format(
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\compiler\__init__.py", line 142, in compile_and_format
    build_json.update(generate_build_json(input_json, output_json, compiler_data, silent))
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\compiler\__init__.py", line 287, in generate_build_json
    source_nodes, statement_nodes, branch_nodes = solidity._get_nodes(output_json)
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\compiler\solidity.py", line 606, in _get_nodes
    source_nodes = solcast.from_standard_output(output_json)
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\solcast\main.py", line 33, in from_standard_output
    source_nodes = set_dependencies(source_nodes)
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\solcast\dependencies.py", line 18, in set_dependencies
    contract.libraries = dict(
  File "C:\Users\provsalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\solcast\dependencies.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    (_get_type_name(i.typeName), i.libraryName.name)
AttributeError: 'UsingForDirective' object has no attribute 'typeName'
```

After looking up this error, it seems to be a bug with using FixedPoint for * at line 617.
Instead of using that syntax, how can I fix this so it doesn't just crash? I'm quite new to solidity frankly and don't understand how this syntax works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is in this string:

```
using FixedPoint for *;
```

in "StandardBondingCalculator.sol" file. I was able to get rid of this error by removing it and changing Valuation(...) function return to:

```
 _value = totalValue.mul( FixedPoint.decode112with18( FixedPoint.fraction( amount_, totalSupply ) ) ).div( 1e18 );
```